# Obtain all the points that lie within a Sphere of radius R and center C in Python

Tags: python

**Problem :** Find all the points which lie inside of a sphere with center C and Radius R

For example find the image below, which explains the problem for a simple 2D case. The label (N) and coordinates (x,y) for each point is known. I need to find all the point labels that lie within the red circle

[image]

Sample input file which contain coordinates of 7.25 M points is attached here [point file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1elSabMbRnwVE1TSlNzYUFXeWc/view?usp=sharing).

I tried the following piece of code

```
import numpy as np

C = [50,50,50]

R = 20 

centroid = np.loadtxt('centroid') #chk the file attached

def dist(x,y): return sum([(xi-yi)**2 for xi, yi in zip(x,y)])

elabels=[i+1 for i in range(len(centroid)) if dist(C,centroid[i])<=R**2]
```

Any Suggestions to make it faster ?

Thanks,
Prithivi

Comment: By a 3d grid of points, do you mean a triply nested list, or some other data structure,

Comment: Let me try to explain in the question..

Comment: you didn't manage to explain the question. the question is about in which data structure your 3D grid is represented.

Comment: Is there a reason this is done as nested lists instead of numpy arrays?

Comment: Also, what would you expect the result look like?  A 1D sequence of values?  If you can't provide a minimal example, can you at least show what MATLAB code you are trying to replicate?  Is the cube a solid block of values or is there "empty" space of some sort?  If so, how is it designated as empty?  Is the cube the same size on each side?  Does each side have equal scaling? What happens if the sphere extends past the edges of the cube?

Comment: Could you guys check it now, apologies for not explaining it properly

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in function to do this.  However, there are constructs to make the search syntactically concise.  There are also geometric packages that include a **Point** data type you might find useful, as well as supporting distance functions.

Without seeing the set-up code you've chosen, about all I can provide is something like this:

```
neighbours = [point for point in point_list if dist(C, point) < R]
```

Another way to approach this construction is to use the **filter** method on **point** list; you'll notice similarities in structure.

---

**Response to Comment**

Is the set-up as shown in your edited problem: the points are spaced regularly?  In that case, drop the list **C** entirely and simply compute the neighbors with a couple of parameters.  If the points are distributed haphazardly, then you can get some speed-up by building a graph of near neighbors to each point.  Then you can use a distance-based graph traversal algorithm to gather the nearby points much faster than by doing a neighborhood search each time.

---

**Simple-minded Insertion**

As you read each point, check it against the existing points in your graph, building the neighbourhoods as you go.  Most of all, use the triangle inequality as your weapon.  For instance, if your current point **x** is at least 2*m units from point **a**, then *no* point in **a**'s neighbourhood can be in **x**'s neighbourhood.

If you wish, you can also maintain a few long-distance links among areas in the graph.  This can allow you to eliminate more distant neighbourhoods from your search.  In general, if you compute d(a,x) to be **q** and d(a,b) to be **r**, then

```
|q-r| <= d(x,b) <= q+r
```

If this range does not include 2*m, then you can similarly eliminate **b**'s entire neighbourhood.

Comment: Thanks! I have made the implementation as shown above. Is there a way to make it faster ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The points  are not spaced regularly in my actual problem. I am not aware of the distance-based graph traversal algorithm that you mentioned. Could you explain that to me or share a link that contains the information. The current code takes about ~ 10 minutes .

Comment: There is no single distance-based algorithm.  I'm suggesting that you build up a graph as you collect the points.  Each new point gets linked to, say, the five nearest points, updating the graph edges as you go.  You can use the distance information to cut down your search greatly.